# media query min-height show anchor top link

Tags: css

I have a "Go to top" link which scroll mobile/tablets to the top of the webpage. Normally I would do this in JS detecting the window and body height.

Is there a way to do this in a media query?

```
@media only screen and (min-height: 500px) and (max-width: 768px) 
{
    .scrollTop { display: block }
}
```

Comment: So you don't want the _Go to Top_ link to appear until the user scrolls a certain amount of the page?

Comment: No that would definitely be a job for javascript, I just want a hide/show in the footer link. Only if the page height is greater than 500px would it show the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion is valid with the inclusion of a **vertical media query**.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
- http://cognition.happycog.com/article/go-vertical
- http://trentwalton.com/2012/01/11/vertical-media-queries-wide-sites/
- http://boagworld.com/dev/vertical-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

You can add an anchor which identifies the top of your page.  On a logo, for example:

```
<a href="/" id="top"><img src="logo.gif" /></a>
```

It's the `id="top"` that's critical.  Then you can just link to `#top` in your "Go to top" link.  Ex:

```
<a href="#top">Go to top</a>
```

If you want this to show only for certain screen sizes, just `display: none` in the media query when you don't want it to show.